# jquery simple swap p element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a p element like so: 
`<p>Something</p>` I want to, when the user mouses over it, we have, instead `<p><a href="blabla.org">go here</a></p>`

After hovering if the mouse leaves the p area, return to the previous:
`<p>Something</p>` state.

Can I have a simple example of something like this?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Comment: Thank you all... I'm having some issues with the ajax call related here... hmm... I will give it a try later on. Thanks a lot for your code examples, I will do my best. K. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or a simple modification of Ken Redler's original that uses `.data()` to keep track of things:

```
$('p#someID').hover( 
    function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('orig', $this.html()).html('<a href="blabla.org">go here</a>');
    },
    function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.html($this.data('orig')).removeData('orig');
    }
);
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FhET2/1/

Comment: Very efficient example (says the person that has had no experience of `.data`). From what I understand of jQuery this is the shortest / quickest way to do what MEM wants. +1 for this also.

Comment: @mu: I believe you. I must try this out sometime (using data- attributes and `.data()` I mean). I have been meaning to do so for ages but have been very busy job hunting and gaming to try.

Comment: @mu: I know it's to short, and I'm sorry, it's just pratical. So, I have two questions: 1) you have write this: var $this = $(this); Why? 2) What is the 'orig' doing there? Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @MEM: I had a problem the other day where either $(this) changed or the scope of $(this) made it inaccessible in the function I tried to reference it in. I guess, in this case, it is just a precaution.

Comment: @MEM: `var $this = $(this)` is there because I need to access `$(this)` twice and I don't want to compute it twice, it is also a habit to avoid having to worry about what `this` is in different places; `.data()` is a simple key/value store, `orig` is the key for tracking the original HTML and `.removeData` cleans up when I don't need `orig` anymore, check http://docs.jquery.com/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** As @Phrogz points out, I missed part of the sense of the question. The suggestions of capturing state with a closure or using `data()` are good ones, but here's another way (with an amusing number of moving parts):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('p#someID').hover( 
    function() { // on mouseEnter
      $(this)
        .contents()
        .wrap('<span class="hide"/>') // wrap 'n' hide
        .end() // back to 'this'
        .append('<a href="blabla.org">Fascinating Link!</a>'); // add link
  }, function() { // on mouseLeave
      $(this)
        .find('a')
        .remove() // kill the anchor
        .end() // back to 'this'
        .find('span.hide') // the wrapper
        .contents() // the wrapped
        .unwrap(); // kill the wrapper, leaving its contents
  });
});
```

This assumes a style like so:

```
span.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Updated example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/redler/HAGzH/1/

Comment: I believe the request was to replace the original text with the anchor, and then restore the original text. (Closure over contents or `.data()` seem appropriate.)

Comment: Huh? So you can end a span using a / without a close tag? I mean like `<span/>`..? Thats news to me...

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy, Yes, in the context of creating new elements with jQuery, you can save those extra few keystrokes. From api.jquery.com/jQuery: `jQuery allows XML-like tag syntax (with or without a space before the slash): $('<a/>');`. An option for the lazy, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Ah ok... I assumed it wasn't just a jQuery specific thing and that it had to be valid html... I knew there were additional selectors such as :visible but I didn't know the input for adding html to an element could be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('p#IDHERE').hover( 
    function(){ // on mouseEnter
      $(this).contents().replaceWith('<a href="blabla.org">go here</a>');
    },
    function(){ // on mouseLeave
      $(this).contents().replaceWith("something");
    }
  );
```

This will replace all text

Comment: From what I understand MEM wants to replace the original text on mouse over and then replace the new text with the original text on mouse out / exit - so the 2nd replaceWith call would have to have the exact same text. Its easy to alter this to account for that, granted, but you may want to adjust your example to suit this.